# Swift Tab Bar и несколько view

Tags: swift, webview, tab

День добрый, подскажите люди добрые!
В моем проекте один Tab Bar Controller и 5 кнопок в нижней панели, каждая из которых по логике должна открывать WebView и определенный URL.
Как правильно сделать (программно или с помощью интерфейса) что бы не плодить ViewController-ы ? То есть что бы не делать 5 вьюшек в каждой из которой будет свой WebView. Возможно ли сделать что бы при нажатии одной из пяти клавиш открывался один и тот же viewcontroller и использовался один webview? Гуглить пробовал - но нужного решения не нашел...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вместо UITabBarController использовать просто UITabBar отдельно, расположив его во ViewController внизу. Только нужно учесть отступы в WebView, т.к, автоматически они не поставятся. Также нужно не забыть про iPhone X - если правельно все сделать, UITabBar сам добавит фон ниже себя, а привязку к низу нужно просто сделать через safeArea.

Если нужно все-таки несколько ViewControllerов, но просто одного класса, то тогда UITabBarController лучше создавать вручную при запуске приложения и создав все 5 экранов, задать их в созданный UITabBarController.

Вот пример кода:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {



        let rootViewController = UITabBarController()
        let viewControllers = (0..<5).map { 
          return WebViewController()
        }
        rootViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)        
        window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! "UITabBar отдельно" - хорошее решение, но и код на будущее тоже сохраню ;-)